# Conditional component rendering outside <router-view> in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

this is my exampleHomeTemplate.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="main-layout">
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

How would it be the most elegant way to make the Footer component to render in all the routes, except for the home ("/") ?

EDIT: **My solution**

this is my "Main layout"

```html
<!-- App.vue --> 
<template>
  <div id="app" class="main-layout">
    <Header />
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is my Footer component

```html
<!-- Footer.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="footer-example-layout" v-if="displayFooter">
    Footer awesome content
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./Footer.ts"></script>
```

```js
// Footer.ts
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

// hide component in this paths
const excludedPaths: string[] = ['/some-other-page', '/login', '/'];

@Component({})
export default class Footer extends Vue {
  get displayFooter() {
    return !excludedPaths.includes(this.$route.path);
  }
}
```

Don't know is this should be the correct approach, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be a conditional rendering with `v-if` on Footer component:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app" class="main-layout">
    <router-view />
    <Footer v-if="$route.path != '/'"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: it works, but let's say if in the future I need to render the footer in the home page also, but hide, or not to render certain elements inside the component ?, is there any way to translate this logic to the component script, and listen for URL changes from inside ?

Comment: `$route` var is global, so you can use it inside each component as you want

Comment: but how would I be listening for changes in the URL if the Footer component is only rendering once on page load ?, maybe I'm confused, sorry if I'm not asking correctly

Comment: @FrancoAguilera When user changes the route, `$route` wil change and v-if will update too. You can set up `v-if` inside `Footer` component and remove `v-if` from App.vue

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this-

1. Use the current route definition and toggle accordingly-

```
<Footer v-if="showFooter"/>
```

```
computed: {
  showFooter() {
    return this.$route.path !== "/";
  }
}
```

2. Use meta property in routes, like-

```
{
  path: `/`,
  name: "Home",
  component: () => import( "@/pages/Home"),
  meta: {
    footer: false,
  },
},
```

```
<Footer v-if="showFooter"/>
```

```
computed: {
  showFooter() {
    let isFooterPropExists = this.$route.meta.hasOwnProperty('footer');
    // Show footer only if meta property not exists OR exists but true
    return !isFooterPropExists || isFooterPropExists && this.$route.meta.footer
  }
}
```

**Note-** In this second approach, you need to add the meta property for the only routes where you don't want to show the footer because by default footer will display for all routes (according to the condition inside the computed property).

Comment: How would you use the computed inside a class like this ?

    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component({})
    export default class Footer extends Vue { }

Comment: I guess you can use like this- https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#computed-properties